# Node JS: Fastest way to read a file on network share

Tags: node.js

I have a NodeJS application that will watch the file system on the network shares. When a new file (XML file) is dropped in one of these shares, the NodeJS application will need to read and parse it. The XML file sizes are all very small, usually around 1k in size.

```
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, content) {
  if (!err) parseXML(content, callback);
}
```

I profiled the app and noticed that it takes average 20 seconds to read one small XML file. I know that these network shares are one part of our file system based workflow and there might be other applications operating on these shares. It is also impossible to have the application running on the machine that owns the share. Is there any other way to improvement the file reading performance? I suppose stream is not an option since I need to parse the XML as a whole.

The application and the file systems are all Windows based.

Thanks!

Comment: 20s to read a 1KB file means your network is extremely, horrendously broken. This has zero to do with node.js. Troubleshoot your host network settings and network infrastructure. Like if I went out for groceries and came back in the year 3045, would you think about buying me better sneakers?

Comment: Talk to your network admins. A 9600 baud modem would be able to send/receive about 24K in the same amount of time. :)

Comment: Good points. We do have some of the shares that are also being worked with other applications like Robocopy and some of them are FTP server folder (hence "file system" based workflow).